# how to return numbers in word format from a string in python

Tags: python

EDIT: The "already answered" is not talking about what I am. My string already comes out in word format. I need to strip those words from my string into a list

I'm trying to work with phrase manipulation for a voice assistant in python.

When I speak something like:

`"What is 15,276 divided by 5?"`

It comes out formatted like this:

`"what is fifteen thousand two hundred seventy six divided by five"`

I already have a way to change a string to an int for the math part, so is there a way to somehow get a list like this from the phrase?

```
['fifteen thousand two hundred seventy six','five']
```

Comment: Yes you can. In this case you can split on divided. How would you split in other cases?

Comment: I think the question is more about converting the numbers to their spelled-out versions than how to make a list of them.

Comment: The numbers already come out in word format. I can change them to an int when it comes to the math

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through the list of words and check each one for membership in a set of numerical words. Add adjacent words to a temporary list. When you find a non-number word, create a new list. Remember to account for non-number words at the beginning of the sentence and number words at the end of the sentence.

```
result = []
group = []
nums = set('one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety hundred thousand million billion trillion quadrillion quintillion'.split())
for word in "what is fifteen thousand two hundred seventy six divided by five".split():
    if word in nums:
        group.append(word)
    else:
        if group:
            result.append(group)
        group = []

if group:
    result.append(group)
```

Result:

```
>>> result
[['fifteen', 'thousand', 'two', 'hundred', 'seventy', 'six'], ['five']]
```

To join each sublist into a single string:

```
>>> list(map(' '.join, result))
['fifteen thousand two hundred seventy six', 'five']
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!